# Learning ggplot2, simple example below does not get desired results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a very simple bar chart, exploring/learning ggplot2.  Can someone tell me what the problem is with the below syntax?  I'm getting a bar with lines all equal to 1:

```
Q2 <- data.frame("Race"=c("White","Black","Asian","MixedRace","NotStated","Other"),
               "Num"=c(6743,885,711,322,553,110))

p <- ggplot(Q2,aes(Race))
p + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying a y-axis aesthetic, which is required by `geom_bar`. What you want is:

```
p <- ggplot(Q2,aes(x = Race, y = Num)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly label the aesthetics, as I have done.

Comment: You can also use `geom_col()` which avoids the need for `stat = "identity"`